Expected value of X, where X - switches made in bubble sort algorithm, if chance of each number being at i-th place is 1/N.
The problem: There is a random sequence of numbers $x_1,x_2,...,x_N$. The chance for each number being at $i$-th place is equal to $1/N$. We use bubble sort algorithm to sort numbers from smallest to largest.
1)Random variable $X_{ij}$ is equal to 1, if $i$-th number is switched with $j$-th number. What is $E[X_{ij}].$
2)Random variable X - how many times the algorithm switches adjacent elements. Compute $E[X]$.
My solution:
Let's denote i-th largest number in the sequence $x_1,x_2,...,x_N$ as $x_i$. Then:

For $x_i = 1, P(X_{1j}=1)=0, P(X_{2j}=1)=\frac{1}{N},...,P(X_{N-1j})=\frac{N-2}{N}$. Then
$$E[X_{ij}] = \left(\frac{1}{N}+\frac{2}{N}+...+\frac{N-1}{N}\right)=\frac{N(N+1)}{2N}=\frac{(N+1)}{2}$$

For the first position the times the $x_i$ can be switched is $\frac{1}{N}\left((N-1)+(N-2)+...+(N-N-1)\right)$. For the second position the times the $x_i$ can be switched: $\frac{1}{N}\left((N-2)+...+(N-N+1)\right)$. For the m-th position the times the $x_i$ can be switched: $\frac{1}{N}\left((N-m)+...+(N-N-1)\right)$. As you can see, I struggle with the second one and am not sure of the first solution as well, so if you can assist anyhow, please do!



For 1, how can the expectation be greater than 1? You're taking the expectation of a 0-1 random variable?
